# 409 ao tentar buscar um CSS

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma paguina web que localmente funciona tudo certinho. Mas quando subo para o servidor ( hostgator) A pagina fica sem um dos arquivos do CSS, olhando no console apare que ao tentar buscar o CSS em questão, houve um conflito ( 409 ), eu já limpei o cache do browser e nada..

O estranho é que em algumas máquinas o codigo funciona normalmente, o CSS consegue ser carregado sem problemas, mas em outras não..

Comment: Tenta o abrir o site no navegador chrome no modo incógnito.

Comment: Deu a mesma coisa..

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como é o setup, Angular, React, Vue, html puro...

Comment: Talvez isso tenha a ver com o tipo e versão do Navegador. Ou seja, a forma como importas os ficheiros `.css` pode não ser suportado por algumas versões e/ou tipo de navegadores. Contudo agradecia se desse mais detalhes.

Comment: Já tentou atualizar a página com o comando ctrl+F5?

Comment: @CristianoGilbertoJoão Eu pensei nisso, mas quando eu ligo o servidor local, ele funciona normalmente, o problema é quando eu subo para o servidor.

Comment: @wensiso já, já limpei o cache, mas isso aconteceu em outras máquinas tbm, mesmo sendo a primeira vez que eu tava abrindo o site lá

Comment: Tira um print do console ai para a gente ver o erro. e tente acessar o seu .CSS direto pelo browser tipo `http://www.meusite.com/css/style.css` (ou o caminho que for ai) para ver o que aparece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não descobri exatamente o motivo do conflito, acredito que tenha sido problema com o hostgator, eu mudei de nome o arquivo CSS e voltou a funcionar em todas as maquinas..